# Turn Airplane Mode on/off via terminal

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

What is the terminal command to turn Airplane Mode on/off in Ubuntu?

Is it simply `sudo rfkill block all` and `sudo rfkill unblock all`? I know that this will disable all wireless modules in the computer, but will this be noticed by the system, so that Airplane Mode is toggled off/on in network settings?

Comment: Try `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`

Comment: @Mitch Do we really need root privileges to climb in an airplane?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu With all the security issues at airports sure :) lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running the following command in terminal:

```
gnome-control-center network
```

will open a window for network management which should be similar with:

[image: Airplane mode on]

You can observe that at this moment the "Airplane Mode" is off and the wireless is on.

Now, without to close this window, run the following command in terminal:

```
nmcli nm wifi off
```

The above window will be changed automatically to:

[image: Airplane mode on]

As you can see, now "Airplane Mode" is on and the wireless is off.

Running, again in terminal, the following command:

```
nmcli nm wifi off
```

will turn "Airplane Mode" off and wireless on again.

So, you don't need `rfkill` (which need also root privileges) to toggle "Airplane Mode" via terminal.

`nmcli` (see also `man nmcli`) it's enough and can be executed by any usual user... *You don't need root privileges to climb in an airplane :))*.

Comment: `nmcli nm wifi off` does not turn off airplane mode unless bluetooth is off.

Comment: For 15.04 it would be: `nmcli r all off` and `nmcli r all on`. Or to include bluetooth: `rfkill block bluetooth & rfkill block wlan` and `rfkill unblock bluetooth & rfkill unblock wlan` .

Comment: For 15.04 (with updates) I found this to work best:   alias  wifitoggle='nmcli r wifi off ; sleep 1 ; nmcli r wifi on'

Comment: Thank you! I was having the same problem. Turns out my laptop was in "flight" mode, but the light indicator wasn't lit...

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 18.04:

`nmcli r wifi on` turns airplane mode **off**, and the converse sets it **on**.

A simple *bash* script to toggle airplane mode on or off is below; save it to file and set its execute bit in properties.

```
#!/bin/bash
wifi="$(nmcli r wifi | awk 'FNR = 2 {print $1}')"
if [ "$wifi" == "enabled" ] 
then
    nmcli r wifi off
else
    nmcli r wifi on
fi
```

Comment: The script has 3 errors. First you do not need to test FNR==2 because the script returns only one line (no headers).  Second if you want to test FNR, then you have to write  FNR == 2. Third the backquote on the line testing the variable wifi has to disappear.

Comment: @RudyVissers, thnaks for catching the errors inserted when a third party "edited" this answer. As for the script *working*, it is currently functioning on a PC with Ubuntu 18,04 in the *original* format, which I've reinstated.

Comment: It is working because `nmcli r wifi` does not return a header and `FNR = 2` has no effect. You can remove `FNR = 2` and your script will continue to work.

Answer (score 3):

By combining answers in different threads, I got it working on Ubuntu 20.04

@Rudy's above and this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1144599/806813

```
#!/bin/bash

radio="$(nmcli radio all | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $2}')"

if [ "$radio" = "enabled" ]
 then
    nmcli radio all off
else
    nmcli radio all on
fi

if rfkill list bluetooth | grep -q 'yes$' ; then
    rfkill unblock bluetooth
else
    rfkill block bluetooth
fi
```

Assigned to Alt-A for me but that is personal choice.

Mind you I already have the built in WiFi adapter on my Lenovo T420 disabled because I am using an Asus USB Wifi adapter which this toggles on and off along with the Bluetooth.

Comment: That works like a charm in Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks!

Comment: and additionally it shows the reassuring airplane icon in top bar.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on 20.04.1 LTS.
Let's disable all radio transmissions:

```
rudy@nbu130-rudy:~/bin$ pwd
/home/rudy/bin

rudy@nbu130-rudy:~/bin$ ./airplane_toggle 

rudy@nbu130-rudy:~/bin$ nmcli radio all 
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled 

rudy@nbu130-rudy:~/bin$ ./airplane_toggle 

rudy@nbu130-rudy:~/bin$ nmcli radio all 
WIFI-HW  WIFI      WWAN-HW  WWAN     
enabled  disabled  enabled  disabled 

rudy@nbu130-rudy:~/bin$ cat airplane_toggle 
#!/bin/bash
radio="$(nmcli radio all | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $2}')"
if [ "$radio" == "enabled" ]
 then
  nmcli radio all off
else
 nmcli radio all on
fi
```

It is even possible to assign the command '/home/rudy/bin/airplane_toggle' to a shortcut (tested).

Comment: This turns wifi off and on on Ubuntu 20.04 but not bluetooth that is already on

Answer (score 1):

On Debian- and Arch-based distros, inspired by the previous code, this will disable WiFi and Bluetooth and send a notification:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
wifi="$(nmcli r wifi | awk 'FNR = 2 {print $1}')"
if [ "$wifi" == "enabled" ]; then
    rfkill block all &
    notify-send 'Mode avion: actif'
else
    rfkill unblock all &
    notify-send 'Mode avion: inactif'
fi
```