# Create a shortcut key to toggle Airplane Mode On/Off

Tags: 13.10, gnome, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-gnome, airplane-mode

I want to create a shortcut key that toggles Airplane Mode On/Off, but do not know what command to use.

To create a shortcut I go to Settings> Keyboard> Shortcuts and then specify a command to be run whenever a given accelerator (shortcut key) is activated.

What command should be specified here to toggle Airplane Mode via a shortcut key?

Note that a while ago [I asked a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/348262/80226), but the answer that I got back then can not be applied here, since a shortcut key command can not change between "on" and "off", but should truly toggle the Airplane Mode not just activate or deactivate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following simple bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

wifi="$(nmcli nm wifi | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1}')"

if [ "$wifi" = "enabled" ]; then
    nmcli nm wifi off
else
    nmcli nm wifi on
fi
```

Don't forget to make it executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script
```

Then add your custom shortcut to this script (it's up to you what shortcut want to choose - it should be something simple for you, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>):

[image: add custom shortcut]

Comment: Oh, it's you again. Hi! :) I can't seem to get this working. I did make a new file `~/scripts/unicornsandrainbows.sh` where I copy-pasted all your above code and made it executable, but when I run `~/scripts/unicornsandrainbows.sh` in a terminal (just to know whether or not it was working) nothing seems to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: @Lindhe94 I updated the script in the time... Maybe you copied first version which had a problem.

Comment: That was totally the case. This is great - you just give the answers to all my answers. Think I'll keep an eye open for your responses from now on. ;)

Comment: This is close, but does not actually toggle the airplane mode, but instead just enable/disables wifi.

Comment: `Error: argument 'nm' not understood. Try passing --help instead.
`

Comment: I used your script, and in the *command* part of the *set custom shortcut* menu, I typed the path to my bash exec. I can execute this exec in my terminal, but it does not work with the shortcut. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Use `nmcli radio wifi` as `nmcli nm` is outdated.

Here is the updated script.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    wifi="$(nmcli radio wifi)"
    
    if [ "$wifi" = "enabled" ]; then
        nmcli radio wifi off
    
    else
        nmcli radio wifi on
    
    fi
```