# Ubuntu does not recognize my Wi-Fi adapter - HP laptop

Tags: networking

*I posted the same question a while ago, I deleted the last one and opened a new one because I have new information which could be of use*

I currently have a partition on my laptop on which I installed ubuntu,the only problem is that for some reason when I try to turn on the Wi-Fi, it says "Wi-Fi adapter not found". With an ethernet cable it runs without any problem.

The thing is, that I really need to be able to connect to the Wi-Fi when am attending University, hence it's an urgent matter for me.

Now I have tried several suggestions (thanks to the helpful community), however nothing worked yet. Tips that I have tried were to run `rfkill unblock all`, it still says my Wi-Fi is hard blocked.

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

output `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` gives:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and output `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[   10.047575] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't find IRQ for PCI INT A; please try using pci=biosirq
[   10.104633] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   10.194732] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[   10.201931] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[   10.215295] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: e4:42:a6:5b:96:bd
[   10.255264] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   11.355172] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

furthermore, I did reset my BIOS which didn't change the situation. Suggestions where to look in the BIOS whether the adapter is disabled. (But in Windows the Wi-Fi works perfectly), I have a picture of this:

[image: Network Adapter]

Lastly, one suggestion was to look for a key on my laptop that enables/disables the Wi-Fi adapter, as far as I know I can't find one.
My laptop is a HP Pavilion Power 15-cb091nd.

For any additional information/questions let me know! thanks for your time!

EDIT: Airplane mode is off, I tried booting to another kernel, both no results

Comment: Isn't there an airplane on the f12 key?

Comment: @mikewhatever Yeah there is, but pressing on it doesn't do anything. I did notice however that the keybinding on my F-keys don't do exactly what they would do in windows. Sound keys work fine for example while brightness doesn't. Might be possible that the F12 key also doesn't work

Comment: Check out this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/348262/turn-airplane-mode-on-off-via-terminal/1104816. Also, have you tried `fn+f12`? Sometimes the order is reversed.

Comment: @Kulfy Oops! certainly not solved, I will ofcourse let the rest know what the problem was once I fix it to help others. If I turn bluetooth on, airplane mode goes off automatically.

Comment: @mikewhatever I checked indeed airplane mode is off.  but still the same "No Wi-Fi adapted connected" issue

Comment: I suggest trying the latest kernel. If it doesn't work, report it as a bug.

Comment: @Pilot6 loaded in the previous Kernel, yet again no difference ;(. Do you perhaps know where I can report bugs? thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean the previous, but the latest mainline kernel. You can report a bug by running `ubuntu-bug linux`, but you'll be asked to test on the latest kernel anyway.

Comment: @Caughtme please see my partial answer. Take special note of `timeshift`. Report back.

Comment: Have you tried enabling Network Boot and disabling Secure Boot? 
[ https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html ]

Comment: @heynnema Hey mate! Thanks for the partial answer, tommorow I will try to follow your steps and I'll report back! thanks in advance

Comment: @Caughtme status update please.

Comment: @Caughtme status update please. Inquiring minds want to know :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at the version of BIOS that you have installed. If it's not `F.17 Rev.A` (*Dec 10, 2018*) then go to the [HP Support Site](https://support.hp.com/au-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-power-15-cb000-laptop-pc/15551388/model/17572307) and download this BIOS update and install it. Reset the BIOS back to factory defaults... leaving Secure Boot disabled, if required. Retest wireless.
2. Try the latest stable kernel 4.20.xx. First... **BACKUP YOUR COMPUTER... AT LEAST THE UBUNTU PART** (*see my note, below, about `Timeshift`*), then install `ukuu`.

   - `sudo apt update` # update the software databases
   - `sudo apt install ukuu` # install Kernel Update Utility for Ubuntu
   - Start ukuu and install kernel 4.20.xx
   - `sudo update-grub` # if ukuu didn't already do this for you
   - `reboot` # reboot the computer and retest wireless

---

**Note: to backup your Ubuntu OS (only) so you can easily restore... install `Timeshift`...**

For those who don't know what Timeshift is...

The closest thing to a Windows-like restore point is by using `Timeshift`. I use it to save snapshots to an external USB hard drive. Although it can, it's normally not used for backing up your /home directory, just system-level changes. Use `Backups` (Déjà Dup) for backing up /home files.

```
Timeshift is a system restore utility which takes snapshots
of the system at regular intervals. These snapshots can be restored
at a later date to undo system changes. Creates incremental snapshots
using rsync or BTRFS snapshots using BTRFS tools.
```

More information at https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift

Add the PPA and install with:

`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install timeshift`