# Ubuntu 20.04 - Is it possible to prioritize network connection?

Tags: networking

I'm using a desktop having 2 networks - Wired (`192.168.2.1`)& Wifi (`192.168.3.1`). Both are from same router that WAN gets it ( WAN -> `192.168.2.1` -> `192.168.3.1`)

Wifi is separated mostly to reduce traffic (IPCAMS) from `192.168.2.1` and sometime internet is disconnected from it to check IOT devices.

Sometimes when Wifi is without internet, Desktop "loses" internet as well (when disconnecting WiFi - internet is back on ). This is not a connectivity issue, Wifi is OK.

So, my question is if there's a way to prioritize Wired network over Wifi ?

Comment: For Networkmanager /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/your-connection-name. `autoconnect-priority=something` (30 for example)

Comment: @nobody sorry, but I did not understand what should I do :/

Comment: What did you look for? What did you find? A search with Ubuntu 20.04 prioritize network connection throws a lot of interesting results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options

1. `ifmetric` ([ref](https://superuser.com/a/1260798/245595)).

**Related**:

1. [How prioritize ethernet over wifi in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177240/how-prioritize-ethernet-over-wifi-in-ubuntu-18-04)
2. https://superuser.com/questions/331720/how-do-i-set-the-priority-of-network-connections-in-ubuntu

Comment: I'll be happy to kn ow if number of priority has any meaning other than smaller than/ bigger than

Comment: It seems like another option is to use NetworkManager [ubuntu-network-management](https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-network-management/)